# How to rotate individual letters around own axis in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to rotate the individual letters of a word around their own axis.
Is it possible to achieve this without wrapping each letter, like in the example bellow?

```css
.word:hover .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<h1 class="word">
  <span class="letter">C</span>
  <span class="letter">H</span>
  <span class="letter">E</span>
  <span class="letter">E</span>
  <span class="letter">S</span>
  <span class="letter">E</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: No, it's not possible for CSS to edit text node content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the text that you want rotated in a span with a specific class and apply a transformation to it.

### DEMO:

```css
.rotated:hover
{
  display: inline-block; 
  transform: scale(-1, 1);
  direction:rtl;
  unicode-bidi:bidi-override;
}
```

```html
<span class='rotated'>CHEESE</span>
```